# Add array values as table rows classes

Tags: jquery

I need to go through array and add it's values as table rows classes where table cells has "colspan=10".

Here is my html:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#"><img src=""></a></td>
    <td width="100%" align="left" colspan="10"><a href="#">Anchor</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1" class="text"><img></td>
    <td valign="top" nowrap="" align="right"><a href="#"><img src=""></a></td>
    <td width="100%" align="left" colspan="9" class="smalltext"><a href="#" class="dottedlink">Anchor</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1" class="text"><img></td>
    <td valign="top" nowrap="" align="right"><a href="#"><img src=""></a></td>
    <td width="100%" align="left" colspan="9" class="smalltext"><a href="#" class="dottedlink">Anchor</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#"><img src=""></a></td>
    <td width="100%" align="left" colspan="10"><a href="#">Anchor</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Please help! I'm totally new in jquery

PS I can add the same class but not from array

Comment: use table class and jquery .each and inside each call td and add class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are asking for

```
var classes = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'whatever']; // <-- your class array

var $cells = $('td[colspan=10]');  // <-- selects table cells with colspan=10

$cells.each(function(index, element){  // <-- executes this function for each cell in the $cells list
    var row = $(element).parent('tr');  // navigate to parent element <tr>
    row.addClass( classes.shift() ); // <-- shift() removes and returns first element in the list
    //   ^-- addClass adds the string as a class without removing previous classes
});
```

Of course that is for educational purposes. In real life you would write the same code more concisely:

```
var classes = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'whatever'];
$('td[colspan=10]').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).parent('tr').addClass(classes.shift());
});
```

Comment: Fyi, you can use `this` instead of `element` so if you only need the element you can just use a function not taking any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

So you have an array like this:

```
var array = [];
array.push('classA');
array.push('classB');
```

Now you want to addo both classes to `<td>` with colspan = 10.

You can do: (EDIT - i added what suggested in the comment)

```
$('td[colspan=10]').each(function(){
     $(this).addClass(array.join(' ')) 
}
```

Comment: `$(this).addClass(array.join(' '))`

Comment: Just as well, `var array = ['classA', 'classB']`

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand clearly what you are trying to achive, but you can get array of your `td` elements with colspan equals to 10 by using query: `$("td[colspan=10]")`, then you can add class to each of them and it can finally look like: `$("td[colspan=10]").addClass("myclass")`. If you will go further you can add those classes not to `td` but to parent `tr` elements:

```
$("td[colspan=10]").each(index, el) {
   el.parents("tr").addClass("myclass");
}
```

Please let me know if it is what you wanted to achive...

Comment: you don't need the apices sourrounding 10